# Firebase - Array of NSObjects not returning normal count value

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query the users under specific company, Then I append it to an NSObjects Array.

Code:

```
var userDetails = [UserDetails]()
func getDriversInfoWithCompany() {

      FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(“users").queryOrderedByChild("company").queryEqualToValue(“KFC").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        let details = UserDetails(key: snapshot.key, snapshot: snapshot.value  as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)

        self.userDetails.append(details)

    self.loadStaffs()                

     }, withCancelBlock: nil)

}

func loadStaffs() {

    let count = self.userDetails.count

    print(count)

    for i in 0...count {

        print(self.userDetails[i].username)

    } 

}
```

And I'm using a for loop to get it's usernames. But I'm having an error `fatal error: Index out of range` Then I `print()` the `count` and the output is 
`1
2
3
4`
 Instead of just `4`. I think How can I get the final value `4` so if i loop it it will not give me an error. Thanks!

EDIT:

```
Code:
    Snap (NU4chDtG7eWKXgPaTuFFDfWXWcf2) {
    company = "KFC";
    email = "user@email.com";
    fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-234esg.appspot.com/o/NU4chDtG7eWKXgPaTuFFDfWXWcf2%2F492003486?alt=media&token=34cecf1e-d65f-4856-8aac-3afdcf9d451e";
    userRole = DISPATCH;
    username = UserName;
    }
    Snap (blkSE7N8GEPeoObNCWLhjyUnkSu2) {
    company = "KFC";
    email = "user@email.com";
    fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-234esg.appspot.com/o/profileImage%2FblkSE7N8GEPeoObNCWLhjyUnkSu2?alt=media&token=b97fd727-12f8-4725-a830-67133de78aab";
    userRole = SHIPPER;
    username = UserName;
    }
    Snap (d605A6Mc0hRWygvK9fjwUnPfliU2) {
    company = "KFC";
    email = "user@email.com";
    fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-234esg.appspot.com/o/profileImage%2Fd605A6Mc0hRWygvK9fjwUnPfliU2?alt=media&token=f35347ca-8da5-402d-a6b6-c3a56f59cbcf";
    userRole = DRIVER;
    username = UserName;
    }
    Snap (fGfIKyF8g5WAOLBdc5dpNSWmaGy2) {
    company = "KFC";
    email = "user@email.com";
    fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-234esg.appspot.com/o/profileImage%2FfGfIKyF8g5WAOLBdc5dpNSWmaGy2?alt=media&token=79735c4e-aa70-4cb0-8a16-b6efedb668a2";
    userRole = DISPATCHER;
    username = "UserName";
    }
```

Code:

```
Snap (users) {

NU4chDtG7eWKXgPaTuFFDfWXWcf2 =     {

company = "KFC";

email = "user@email.com";

fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-234esg.appspot.com/o/NU4chDtG7eWKXgPaTuFFDfWXWcf2%2F492003486?alt=media&token=34cecf1e-d65f-4856-8aac-3afdcf9d451e";

userRole = DISPATCH;

username = UserName;

};

blkSE7N8GEPeoObNCWLhjyUnkSu2 =     {

company = "KFC";

email = "user@email.com";

fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-234esg.appspot.com/o/profileImage%2FblkSE7N8GEPeoObNCWLhjyUnkSu2?alt=media&token=b97fd727-12f8-4725-a830-67133de78aab";

userRole = SHIPPER;

username = UserName;

};

d605A6Mc0hRWygvK9fjwUnPfliU2 =     {

company = "KFC";

email = "user@email.com";

fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-234esg.appspot.com/o/profileImage%2Fd605A6Mc0hRWygvK9fjwUnPfliU2?alt=media&token=f35347ca-8da5-402d-a6b6-c3a56f59cbcf";

userRole = DRIVER;

username = UserName;

};

fGfIKyF8g5WAOLBdc5dpNSWmaGy2 =     {

company = "KFC";

email = "user@email.com";

fileUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myapp-234esg.appspot.com/o/profileImage%2FfGfIKyF8g5WAOLBdc5dpNSWmaGy2?alt=media&token=79735c4e-aa70-4cb0-8a16-b6efedb668a2";

userRole = DISPATCHER;

username = "UserName";

};

}
```

The first one is .ChildValue, And the second one is .Value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your **`loadStaff()`** function to :-

```
func loadStaffs() {

        let count = self.userDetails.count
        print(count)

            for i in 0...count-1 {

             print(self.userDetails[i].username)

             } 
         }
```

For retrieving use :-

```
func getDriversInfoWithCompany() {

  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(“users").queryOrderedByChild("company").queryEqualToValue(“KFC").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{ 

      for each in snapDict as [String:AnyObject]{

      let details = UserDetails(key: each.0, snapshot: each.1  as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)

     self.userDetails.append(details)

     self.loadStaffs()                

   } 
  }
 }, withCancelBlock: nil)

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *But still the count is repeating*. I am not able to understand you? Are you asking why `loadStaff() ` is being called everytime and you want it to call when all the values have been appended?

Comment: Because it will as long as you are using `childAdded` eventCall. It fires completionBlock every time after retrieving a single node. Change `childAdded` to `.Value` and then loop over your retrieved snapshot to fire your `loadStaff()` function only once :)

Comment: I changed it to .Value and now it returns nothing. What do you think seems to be the problem? Should i change my query?

Comment: Have you tried printing the snapshot? is that nil? Also since now you are retrieving the entire JSON with `.Value` eventType you need to loop over each key-value.

Comment: snapshot is not nil, But the key is changed to `users` instead of the `uid` of the user. How can i make this work?

Comment: Update your question with your JSON structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125347/discussion-between-levis-ogcpas-and-dravidian).

Comment: Answer Updated :)

Comment: It worked, I can now get data from snapshot. But the count is still the same :( it loops it continuously.